# I can't connect to a remote postgresql database

Tags: postgresql

The error itself:
psql: error: connecting to server "10.10.99.1", port 5432 failed: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.10.99.3", user "eprt_admin", database "postgresql", SSL encryption
failed to connect to server "10.10.99.1", port 5432: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "10.10.99.3", user "eprt_admin", database "postgresql", no encryption

pg_hba.conf:

```
#IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    all         eprt_admin  10.10.99.3/32       md5
host    all         eprt_admin  10.10.99.1/32       md5
#IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
#Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
#replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

Comment: im using ubuntu

Comment: Either you didn't reload PostgreSQL, or the reload failed (check the log), or you modified the `pg_hba.conf` for a different server.

Comment: seems to have restarted

Comment: Introduce an intentional syntax error.  If it still restarts with the error, then you know the file you edited is not the one being used.

Answer (score 0):

Add or edit the following line in your postgresql.conf :

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

Restart Postgresql after adding this with `service postgresql restart` or the equivalent command for your setup.

source:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host